Spresense ArduinoのAudio チュートリアル「MP3の音楽を再生する」がコアダンプし実行できない
Spresense Arduinoの Audio チュートリアル 「MP3の音楽を再生する」の手順に従いプログラムを実行したところ、コアダンプが出力されプログラム実行できません。
解決方法をご存じの方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？
IDEとLibraryのバージョンは下記になります。
Arduino IDE 2.3.2
Spresense Library 3.2.0
以下、コアダンプの内容です。
19:19:09.142 -> mpshm_init() failure. -12
19:19:09.142 -> Memory pool arm_hardfault: Hard Fault escalation:
19:19:09.142 -> arm_hardfault: PANIC!!! Hard Fault!:
19:19:09.142 -> arm_hardfault:  IRQ: 3 regs: 0xd0600e0
19:19:09.194 -> arm_hardfault:  BASEPRI: 000000e0 PRIMASK: 00000000 IPSR: 00000003 CONTROL: 00000000
19:19:09.194 -> arm_hardfault:  CFSR: 00008200 HFSR: 40000000 DFSR: 00000000 BFAR: 000601dc AFSR: 00000000
19:19:09.194 -> arm_hardfault: Hard Fault Reason:
19:19:09.194 -> _assert: Current Version: NuttX  12.3.0 SDK3.2.0-8e5b871 Feb  9 2024 14:56:53 arm
19:19:09.194 -> _assert: Assertion failed panic: at file: :0 task: spresense_main 0xd001509
19:19:09.211 -> up_dump_register: R0: b1110000 R1: ffffffff R2: 0d0601bc  R3: 0149250d
19:19:09.211 -> up_dump_register: R4: 0d060200 R5: 0d04fcc0 R6: 000601dc  FP: 000601d4
19:19:09.211 -> up_dump_register: R8: 00000000 SB: 00000000 SL: 00000000 R11: 00000000
19:19:09.211 -> up_dump_register: IP: 00000001 SP: 0d0601b8 LR: 0d006f55  PC: 0d006f5a
19:19:09.211 -> up_dump_register: xPSR: 21000000 BASEPRI: 000000e0 CONTROL: 00000000
19:19:09.211 -> up_dump_register: EXC_RETURN: ffffffed
19:19:09.211 -> dump_stack: User Stack:
19:19:09.211 -> dump_stack:   base: 0xd05e2e0
19:19:09.242 -> dump_stack:   size: 00008160
19:19:09.242 -> dump_stack:     sp: 0xd0601b8
19:19:09.242 -> stack_dump: 0xd0601a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d006f55 000000ff 000601d4
19:19:09.242 -> stack_dump: 0xd0601c0: 0d03985c 0d060220 0d04fcc0 0d00660d 0d060220 00000000 00007fff 0000025c
19:19:09.242 -> stack_dump: 0xd0601e0: 00000000 00000000 0d04fcc0 0d04a404 0d04fda0 0d000c17 00000000 0d01d8af
19:19:09.242 -> stack_dump: 0xd060200: 80000000 00000001 0d05e114 0d018889 0d05e118 0d05e114 0d04a404 0d02421d
19:19:09.276 -> stack_dump: 0xd060220: 025c0018 0d017100 0d05e118 0d017195 0000001d 0d01746d 0d0386b3 0a000000
19:19:09.276 -> stack_dump: 0xd060240: 00007fff 00000000 00000000 0d0002ed 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
19:19:09.276 -> stack_dump: 0xd060260: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d024fd8 01000000 00000000 00000000
19:19:09.276 -> stack_dump: 0xd060280: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d001509 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d001529
19:19:09.307 -> stack_dump: 0xd0602a0: 00000001 0d02c62f 0d05e2c8 00000001 0d05e2c8 0d025017 00000000 00000000
19:19:09.307 -> dump_tasks:    PID GROUP PRI POLICY   TYPE    NPX STATE   EVENT      SIGMASK          STACKBASE  STACKSIZE      USED   FILLED    COMMAND
19:19:09.307 -> dump_tasks:   ----   --- --- -------- ------- --- ------- ---------- ---------------- 0xd050eb0      2048       632    30.8%    irq
19:19:09.341 -> dump_task:       0     0   0 FIFO     Kthread N-- Ready              0000000000000000 0xd053c54      1016       564    55.5%    Idle_Task
19:19:09.341 -> dump_task:       1     1 224 RR       Kthread --- Waiting Semaphore  0000000000000000 0xd055210      1992       312    15.6%    hpwork 0xd052ff8 0xd05300c
19:19:09.376 -> dump_task:       2     2 100 RR       Kthread --- Waiting Semaphore  0000000000000000 0xd055df0      1992       624    31.3%    lpwork 0xd053020 0xd053034
19:19:09.376 -> dump_task:       3     3 100 RR       Kthread --- Waiting Semaphore  0000000000000000 0xd0569d0      1992       312    15.6%    lpwork 0xd053020 0xd053048
19:19:09.376 -> dump_task:       4     4 100 RR       Kthread --- Waiting Semaphore  0000000000000000 0xd0575b0      1992       312    15.6%    lpwork 0xd053020 0xd05305c
19:19:09.412 -> dump_task:       6     6 200 RR       Task    --- Waiting MQ empty   0000000000000000 0xd059120       992       464    46.7%    cxd56_pm_task
19:19:09.412 -> dump_task:       7     7 255 RR       Kthread --- Waiting Semaphore  0000000000000000 0xd05d848       992       312    31.4%    gnss_receiver
19:19:09.412 -> dump_task:       8     8 100 RR       Task    --- Running            0000000000000000 0xd05e2e0      8160       584     7.1%    spresense_main


mpshm_init() failure.というログが表示されているので、スケッチに割り当てているメモリサイズが大きすぎるのではないでしょうか。
Arduinoチュートリアルのメモリサイズ変更を参考に、例えば、Memoryを768 KBへ変更して試してみてください。
アプリケーション用メモリにある表をみると、MP3の音楽再生をするためには、各種バッファ(256KB)とMP3DECデコーダ(128KB)用のメモリ領域は空けておく必要がありそうなので、スケッチに割り当てられるメモリは最大で1152KB(=1.5MB - 256KB - 128KB) になるのかなと思います。

ご回答ありがとうございます。
スケッチのメモリサイズが最大の1536KBになっており、これをデフォルトの768KBに
変更してコアダンプを吐かずにMP3の再生ができました。
ありがとうございました。
